# Parse search params in relative URL in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a relative URL, something like `/a/b?someParam=cccc`

I want to extract the value of the parameter. One alternative is to do  `(new URL(myUri, 'http://example.com')).searchParams.get('someParam')`. It is nice because it uses the built-in functions from the browser and it is going to be safe in cases when the parameter of the url is encoded.

However, it depends on a random base of the url `http://example.com`. Is there a way to parse a URL without a base? Or to extract the search params?

Comment: This is a duplicate question. Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Comment: @VeteranSlayer how is that a duplicate? In that question they have an URL, not an URI. My problem is that the only way that I know is to first create an URL and then use that question. But creating the url seems to require a random base

Comment: You could just use `window.location.origin` if you need a base. Or get everything after the `?` and pass it to [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams) directly

Comment: @Reyno I think yours is the best proposal, feel free to post it as an answer and I'll approve it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could take everything after the `?` and pass it directly to [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams).

```js
const getParamsFromURI = ( uri ) => {
  // Get everything after the `?`
  const [ , paramString ] = uri.split( '?' );

  // Return parameters
  return new URLSearchParams( paramString );
};

const params = getParamsFromURI( '/a/b?someParam=cccc' );
console.log( params.get( 'someParam' ) );
```

Or if you want to use the [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) constructor you can get a base from `window.location.origin`

```js
const getParamsFromURI = ( uri ) => {
  // Create url with base
  const base = window.location.origin; // Could also be a fixed value e.g. http://example.com
  const url = new URL( uri, base );
  
  // Return parameters
  return url.searchParams;
};

const params = getParamsFromURI( '/a/b?someParam=cccc' );
console.log( params.get( 'someParam' ) );
```

Comment: This does not work, if the url contains a "fragment" (`#something` at the end). For example `http://www.example.com/abc?bar=baz#someSection`

Comment: This doesn't work if the url contains multiple ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const paramString = "/a/b?someParam=cccc".split("?")[1];
const params = new URLSearchParams(paramString);
const result = Object.fromEntries(params.entries());
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could manipulate the string like this

```
var test = "/a/b?someParam=cccc&someotherparam=bbb";
var params = test.split('?')[1].split('&').map( (e) => {
    let temp = e.split('=');
    let rObj = {};
   rObj[temp[0]] = temp[1];
   return rObj;
} );

console.log(params);
```

At first you split the string to two segments (before and after "?"). Then you split again the second part by the "&" symbol to generate an array of strings.
In the end you map the array to generate an object with keys and values.

I hope the helps.

**EDIT**

If you want to use the method `URLSearchParams` you could do it like this

```
var test = "/a/b?someParam=cccc&someotherparam=bbb";

var params = new URLSearchParams(test.split('?')[1]);

console.log(params.get("someParam"));
```

Comment: I think OP wanted to use builtin objects as much as possible, not reinvent the parsing mechanism. You're also only reinventing it partially, you're missing the decoding step for values.

Comment: @deceze Check my edited answer if it solves the problem.

Comment: Yeah, better. That's probably as good as it gets.

Answer (score -2):

`var url_string = "/a/b?someParam=cccc";`

function getParam( name, url ) {

```
if (!url) url = location.href;
name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
var results = regex.exec( url );
return results == null ? null : results[1];
```

}

`console.log(getParam('someParam', url_string))`

Comment: That would work if the search params was in my window.location, but I have the relative URL in a variable

Comment: @GabrielFurstenheim please see i have posted a updated function

Comment: Hi @Muhammad, parsing and decoding is hard and shouldn't be done with regexes. That's why I'm using built in functions